# recursion in nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

find the addition of nested object using recursion
here my **sum** is always passed as 10 ??.........
I am trying to add sum value in else condition but in if it always pass as 10

```js
let abc = { a: 10, b: { a: 20 }, c: { b: { a: 30 } } };

const Formation = (obj,sum) =>{

  for(let ky in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[ky] == 'object') {
       Formation(obj[ky],sum);
    } else {
      sum += obj[ky] ? obj[ky] : 0;
    }
  // console.log(sum)
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log('res: ', Formation(abc, 0));
```

Comment: You need replace `Formation(obj[ky],sum);` with `sum += Formation(obj[ky],sum);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because you don't use returned value from nested Formation.
You need make some changes to your code:

```
let abc = { a: 10, b: { a: 20 }, c: { b: { a: 30 } } };

const Formation = (obj) =>{
  let sum = 0;

  for(let ky in obj){
    if(typeof obj[ky] == 'object'){
      sum += Formation(obj[ky]);
    }
    else{
      sum += obj[ky] ? obj[ky] : 0;
    
    }
  // console.log(sum)
  }
  return sum;
}
```